# Output after Triangulation (MATLAB) isn't accurate

Tags: matlab, matlab-cvst, coordinate-transformation, stereo-3d

I am using MATLAB- CVST to perform Stereo Camera Calibration. From 28 images (6 X 7 corners), *stereoParams* are obtained (*stereoParams.MeanReprojectionError* = 0.3168).

Next, I took took a checkerboard stereo pair (*CB_I1* & *CB_I2*).

To *CB_I1* I applied the following functions:

1. undistortImage
2. detectCheckerboardPoints
3. generateCheckerboardPoints
4. extrinsics: This gives me Translation vector (T) and Rotation Matrix (R)

Next, To both CB_I1 & CB_I2, I apply the following functions:

1. undistortImage
2. detectCheckerboardPoints
3. triangulate: this gives me *worldPoints*
4. Inverse Translation and Rotation Transform

This is my code:

```
CB_I1_undist = undistortImage(CB_I1, stereoParams.CameraParameters1);
CB_I2_undist = undistortImage(CB_I2, stereoParams.CameraParameters2);

[imagePoints1, ~] = detectCheckerboardPoints(CB_I1_undist);
[imagePoints, ~] = detectCheckerboardPoints(CB_I2_undist);

worldPoints = triangulate(imagePoints1,imagePoints,stereoParams);

Translated_pnts = zeros(size(worldPoints));
Translated_pnts(:,1) = worldPoints(:,1) - T(1);
Translated_pnts(:,2) = worldPoints(:,2) - T(2);
Translated_pnts(:,3) = worldPoints(:,3) - T(3);
Rotated_pnts = Translated_pnts * (R');

Transformed_points = Rotated_pnts;
```

Ultimately, *Transformed_points* looks like this:

[image]

and so on....for 42 points.

How do I interpret this? I expect *Transformed_points* to be:

[image]

since each square size is 40mm.

- Primarily, is this an error?
- What is the cause? Is it because of the high reprojection error? (if so, how can it be minimised?)
- How can I reduce this as much as possible?
- I want this as close as possible to the ideal value.  What are the different ways by which I can improve my algorithm's accuracy?

Let me know if you need any other information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say you have a mean re-projection error of 0.3~.

If I calculate the distance between your first and second point:

```
sqrt((-0.2006+0.1993)^2+(-1.2843-39.1922)^2+(3.0466-2.0656)^2)
ans >>
      40.4884
```

Well thats what you expect right? Its not 100% accurate of course.

Also,look again at your points. They are exactly where you expect them to be. Instead of 120 you have 120.06. Instead of 160, you have 159.94.

you are missing the points by around 0.3 millimeters. **0.3 MILIMETERS**. 
Take a ruler and try to measure 0.3 millimeters!!

- Thats 4 time a human hair!
- Its more or less the minimum distance the human eye can distinguish!
- 3 times the with of paper!
- 0.6 times the size OF A BACTERIA! (amoeba Proteus)

WOW, I think thats a quite good error to have, dont you?

Anyway, you can decrease that error using more calibration images, but yeah, I'd say you are doing a good job already.

A good way of measuring the error so it has more meaning is to calculate the pixel error, not the real physical error. If you divide the error by the length of a pixel, you can know how many pixels of error you have. You will see that most likely in your case you are having sub-pixel accuracy (pixel error < 1). This is very good because it means that your error is smaller than what you can measure, so, in some sense (not really, but yeah) you are breaking the Shanon principle! Good job

---

<sub>Source of random data: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=300+micrometres</sub>

Comment: :D That's right! Well, yeah, I am indeed working with really high accuracy. Ultimately, I am calculating angles which should have an accuracy of +/- 1 arc-min, over a distance of around 1m from the baseline. I want to decrease the mean reprojection error as much as possible.

Comment: @Meghana Nice! Consider converting your errors to pixels (so you can see sub-pixel accuracy better) and consider accepting the answer also ;)

Comment: MATLAB uses sub-pixel accuracy during calibration by default, right? So I need not do additional processing.

I will definitely accept an answer. I really want more opinions regarding this issue of mine, it's holding my project back.

Comment: "sub pixl accuracy" refers to the quality of the output, is not something "MATLAB uses". If the error in mm divided by length of pixels in mm is smaller than one, then it means that the error is smaller than a pixel, thus, you can obtain sub-pixel accuracy. @Meghana . I have worked in an application where way more accuracy than what you describe was needed. The only options to get better accuracy on the calibrations are:

Comment: 1.- Get better cameras (more resolution). 2.- Use a bigger amount of photos when calibrating and print the check board in high quality paper. 3.- use advanced calibration techniques, using circular calibration patterns  and some quite adnvanced optimization techniques. Unless you do any of these, you are as good as you can

Comment: That's cool! @AnderBiguri

1. Currently, I am using 10MP sensors. Changing this is my last option, since the hardware has already been developed. 

2. Yes, it is the best quality I could get, but I will look into this again. Thank you.

3. I am using MATLAB, which supports checkerboard patterns. Could you tell me what software you used? Did you too use circular calibration patterns? 

Please elaborate on " quite advanced optimization techniques"

Comment: @Meghana Unfortunately I didn't do it :(. There was a PhD student doing that for his thesis. You can google it and you find different camera models/minimization algorithms/patterns. this is a whole reearch field that cant be asnwered in a single SO question, unfortunatedly!

Answer (score 1):

To Ander's answer I would just like to add that you should be sure to measure the square size very precisely, using a caliper. If you can get sub-millimeter accuracy on that, that will have an effect on your reconstruction accuracy. Also, please be sure not to use lossy compression on your images, i. e. no jpeg. Jpeg artifacts will also decrease your accuracy.

Comment: Thanks, I wanted your opinion too. And yes, my images are in .png format. Should I switch to .bmp? Is this the one with minimal / no compression?

Comment: Png is fine. Just make sure that the images come off the cameras uncompressed.